# parse/get json from spring mvc controller in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, spring-mvc

I want to access json data from spring controller in javascript.
This is the restapi call which returns json data

```
{id: '0', item: [
    {
        id: 'all',
        text: 'ALL',
        item: [
            {
                id: 'all-',
                text: 'ALL-',
                item: [
                    {
                        id: 'Market1-0',
                        text: 'Market1',
                        item: [
                            {
                                id: 'id2',
                                text: 'Project 2'
                            },
                            {
                                id: 'id1',
                                text: 'Project 1'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here is the code for Spring handler

```
public class DashboardHandler {

public String getProjects() throws ParseException{

    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory rf = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    rf.setReadTimeout(50000);
    rf.setConnectTimeout(50000);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(rf);
    String page = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "http://localhost:9090/mcps/api/v1.0/user/2/projects",
            String.class);

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject customerListObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(page);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("{id:'0', item:[");
    builder.append("{id:'all', text:'ALL', item:[");
    int i=0;
    for (Object customer : customerListObject.keySet()) {
        JSONObject customerJsonObject = (JSONObject) customerListObject
                .get(customer.toString());
        for (Object region : customerJsonObject.keySet()) {
            JSONObject marketJsonObject = (JSONObject) customerJsonObject
                    .get(region.toString());
            for (Object market : marketJsonObject.keySet()) {
                builder.append("{id:'"+market+"-"+i+"', text:'"+market+"', item:[");
                i++;
                JSONObject projectObject = (JSONObject) marketJsonObject
                        .get(market.toString());
                for(Object projectId:projectObject.keySet()){
                    JSONObject projectJsonObject = (JSONObject) projectObject.get(projectId);
                    for(Object project: projectJsonObject.keySet()){
                        builder.append("{id:'"+projectId+"', text:'"+project+"'},");
                    }
                }

                builder.append("]},");
            }

        }
    }
    builder.append("]}]}");
    System.out.println(builder.toString());

    return builder.toString();
}

}
```

And i have controller with request mapping url

```
@Controller
public class DashboardController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/getProjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getProjects(HttpServletRequest request) {
    DashboardHandler dashBoardHandler = new DashboardHandler();
    try {
        return dashBoardHandler.getProjects();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}

}
```

So now i want to acces that /getProjects url in javascript. 
Can anyone tell me how?

Comment: Have you tried to search for something like "js get json"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
type : 'GET',
url : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getProjects',
success : function(data) {
//parse json data
alert(data.id);
$('#mydiv').append(data.id);
//data.id is 0
//data.item[0].id is 'all'
//data.item[0].text is 'ALL'
//data.item[0].item[0].id is 'all-'
//data.item[0].item[0].text is 'ALL-'
//data.item[0].item[0].item[0].id is 'Market1-0'
//data.item[0].item[0].item[0].text is 'Market1'
}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='mydiv'>Hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Cant we do this with javascript only??

Comment: I not sure. But jquery very popular in web development. It make more convinience for develper.